# eregi_replace to preg_replace conversion stuff

Tags: regex

Regular expressions are not strong point.
I can do simple stuff, but this one has just got my goat !!
So could someone give me a hand with this one.

Here's the comment in the code :

// If utf8 detection didnt work before, strip those weird characters for an underscore, as a last resort.

```
eregi_replace("[^a-z0-9 \-\.\(\)\/\\]","_",$str);
```

to (here's what I tried)

```
preg_replace("{[^a-z0-9 \-\.\(\)\/\\]}i","_",$str);
```

Any regex pros out there who give me a hand?

Comment: Nevermind , I got it.  it becomes preg_replace("{[^a-z0-9]\-\.\(\)\/\\/}i","_",$str)

Comment: I'd be careful, though - I don't think the `eregi_replace` and your proposed `preg_replace` expressions are even nearly equivalent. I would recommend testing it thoroughly, then if you still feel it is the answer, post it as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify regexp identifier such as `#` or `/`

```
preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9 \-\.\(\)\/\\]#i","_",$str);
```

So you should enclose your regular expression in those identifier characters.

Comment: PHP has supported both types of delimiting for a while, so that is not a/the problem with the expression, though it's probably not a bad idea to change them anyways!

Answer (score 1):

First, I believe the `{` and `}` are fine as delimiters for the expression from the flags, but I know there are some regex flavors that don't support it, so it might be a good idea to just use something like `!` or `#`

Second, I am not sure how the expression before worked, because AFAIK escaping with a `\` character does not work with ERE expressions. You have to represent special characters like `^`, `-`, and `]` by their position within the class (`^` cannot be the first character, `]` must be the first character, and `-` must be either the first or the last character). The `-` character in the first expression would be interpreted as a range specifier (in this case a character in the range between `\` and `\`). Additionally, the `\` characters are treated literally, so you've got a confusing looking and largely redundant regex.

The replacement expression, however, needs to be in preg notation/flavor, so there are rule changes:

- Very few things *need* to be escaped in a character class, even with the new rules
- The `\` character needs to be escaped twice - once for the string, and then one more time for the regex - otherwise, it will escape the closing bracket `]`
- Assuming you want to match a dash (or rather match something OTHER than a dash, it needs to be moved to the end of the class

So, here is some [code (link)](http://codepad.org/zK3zM9Eo) that I believe does what you need it to do:

```
$source = 'hello! @#$%^&* wazzup-dawg?.()/\\[]{}<>:"';
$blah = preg_replace('![^a-z0-9 .()/\\\\-]!i','_',$source);

print($blah);
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace("{[^a-z0-9]-.()/\/}i","_",$str)

works just fine.

I tried it with all # and / and { and they all worked.